# Wake from suspend issues

Tags: suspend

I'm running 18.04 and am having problems waking from suspend. When I open the lid, a TTY session is opened and the following is displayed:

```
[drm:intel_display_resume [i915]] *ERROR* Restoring old state failed with -22
```

Sometimes, no TTY is displayed and the screen remains blank.

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, do you use a thinkpad x1 carbon gen6 ? I am ashamed to say, I won't most likely be able to help you because I am brand new to Ubuntu. But before installing it on my laptop, I did massive research to know what to expect and ran into a few posts about suspend on the archwiki and lenovo's forums. Maybe you have the same issue.

Comment: No, this isn't on a ThinkPad. It's a Revo P65_P67RGRERA. It is, however, a 6th gen Intel CPU: core i7-6820HK.